# Create object from a string, javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, object

Is it possible to create an object from a string content?

For example, I have a string `"{ name: John }"` how can I simply parse it to create an object `{ name: 'John' }` ?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately `JSON.parse` won't work for me, there can be also some tricky strings (if you used mongodb you know), e.g. `{ name: John, email: { $exists: true } }`

Maybe there is another solution like mongodb query parser?

Comment: Why are you using this format?

Comment: Where are you getting these strings from?

Comment: user puts them into shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way to do it.
//code for trim method

```
 if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
      String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
      }
    }

    var s =  "{ name: John }";
    var arr = s.substring(1,s.length-1).trim().split(':');
    var obj = {};
    obj[arr[0]]=arr[1];

    alert(obj.name);
```

Comment: What about `"{ name: John, family: Resig }"` ?

Comment: this kind of technique I already use, for ``"{ name: John, family: Resig }"`` you need to split it before on ``,``

Comment: but in my case there can be even more complicated techniques like ``{ name: John, email: { $exists: true }}``

Answer (score 0):

If you can get `'{"name":"John"}'` then you can just decode it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txzd7/1/)**

Your string must be valid JSON format:

```
var s = '{ "name": "John", "family": "Resig" }';
```

Then you can parse it with `JSON.parse`:

```
var o = JSON.parse(s);
```

And you can use the object `o`:

```
alert(o.name); // John
alert(o.family); // Resig
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't be sure that it will be correct JSON, a string could be like this ``{ data: $exists }``, seems only spliting & slicing may help

Comment: @Kosmetika How are you generating your JSON? All server side languages has ability to generate **valid** JSON string.

Comment: it's not a JSON, it's simple string that user puts into shell

Comment: @Kosmetika I don't think it's a correct way to do this. Imagine user wants something like this: `{ "fullname": "Resig, John: jQuery Creator" }` (an object with one pair). How this must be input? `{ fullname: Resig, John: jQuery Creator }` (an object with two pairs)?

Comment: yeah, sounds not ok.. in ideal it can be typed like { fullname: "Resig, John: jQuery Creator" }..